# Return NA if date is lower than for specific rows in R

Tags: r, na, as.date

My data looks like this:

```
dput(head(VI_v2_KRR05,28))
structure(list(ID = c("AUR", "AUR", "AUR", "AUR", "AUR", "AUR", 
"AUR", "AUR", "AUR", "AUR", "AUR", "LAM", "LAM", "LAM", "LAM", 
"LAM", "LAM", "LAM", "LAM", "LAM", "LAM", "P0", "P0", "P0", "P0", 
"P0", "P01", "P01"), EVI_SOS = structure(c(16440, 16805, 17124, 
17421, 17599, 17851, 18216, 18403, NA, NA, NA, 16272, 16406, 
16637, 16771, 17148, 17516, 17725, 18022, 18210, NA, 16692, 16845, 
17058, 17212, NA, 16717, 17077), class = "Date"), NDVI_SOS = structure(c(16436, 
16801, 17110, 17420, 17607, 17841, 18196, 18402, NA, NA, NA, 
16270, 16380, 16635, 16745, 17139, 17274, 17522, 17731, 18027, 
18198, 16480, 16683, 17055, NA, NA, 16712, 17076), class = "Date"), 
    NIRv_SOS = structure(c(16424, 16557, 16789, 16922, 17221, 
    17379, 17607, 17821, 17931, 18214, 18400, 16274, 16404, 16639, 
    16769, 17145, 17519, 17727, 18028, 18208, NA, 16695, 16848, 
    17061, 17218, NA, 16720, 17084), class = "Date"), kNDVI_SOS = structure(c(16542, 
    16799, 17212, 17431, 17607, 17854, 18003, 18219, 18401, NA, 
    NA, 16282, 16647, 17139, 17516, 17733, 18026, 18205, NA, 
    NA, NA, 16474, 16706, 16847, 17073, 17209, 16712, 17075), class = "Date"), 
    EVI_EOS = structure(c(16766, 17084, 17356, 17577, 17812, 
    18098, 18385, 18585, NA, NA, NA, 16375, 16618, 16740, 17099, 
    17452, 17707, 17841, 18183, 18549, NA, 16825, 17012, 17193, 
    17396, NA, 17022, 17398), class = "Date"), NDVI_EOS = structure(c(16768, 
    17075, 17375, 17590, 17812, 18095, 18385, 18568, NA, NA, 
    NA, 16359, 16616, 16724, 16998, 17248, 17490, 17714, 17961, 
    18177, 18460, 16648, 17020, 17393, NA, NA, 17028, 17392), class = "Date"), 
    NIRv_EOS = structure(c(16533, 16768, 16899, 17191, 17358, 
    17590, 17798, 17920, 18104, 18379, 18547, 16373, 16619, 16738, 
    17086, 17441, 17709, 17839, 18182, 18471, NA, 16828, 17008, 
    17198, 17387, NA, 17028, 17398), class = "Date"), kNDVI_EOS = structure(c(16764, 
    17184, 17356, 17592, 17805, 17993, 18088, 18381, 18562, NA, 
    NA, 16620, 17007, 17439, 17715, 17845, 18180, 18457, NA, 
    NA, NA, 16625, 16833, 16991, 17192, 17366, 17026, 17391), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to return NA the dates lower than *2015-09-04* for the `ID` **AUR**, *2015-09-04* for the `ID` **LAM**, *2016-01-02* for the `ID` **P0** and *2016-01-09* for the `ID` **P01**.

Any help will be much appreciatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when` if there are only few IDs i.e. create the condition for each ID separately to return only the values that are greater than the threshold date or else, the default case in `case_when` returns NA.

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)
out <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is_date), 
   ~ case_when(.x > as.Date("2015-09-04") & ID == 'AUR' ~ .x,
     ID == "LAM" & .x > as.Date("2015-09-04 ") ~ .x, 
     ID == "P0" & .x > as.Date("2016-01-02 ") ~ .x, 
     ID == "P01" &  .x > as.Date("2016-01-09") ~ .x)))
```

-checking

```
> df1 %>% filter(ID == "LAM")
# A tibble: 10 × 9
   ID    EVI_SOS    NDVI_SOS   NIRv_SOS   kNDVI_SOS  EVI_EOS    NDVI_EOS   NIRv_EOS   kNDVI_EOS 
   <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 LAM   2014-07-21 2014-07-19 2014-07-23 2014-07-31 2014-11-01 2014-10-16 2014-10-30 2015-07-04
 2 LAM   2014-12-02 2014-11-06 2014-11-30 2015-07-31 2015-07-02 2015-06-30 2015-07-03 2016-07-25
 3 LAM   2015-07-21 2015-07-19 2015-07-23 2016-12-04 2015-11-01 2015-10-16 2015-10-30 2017-09-30
 4 LAM   2015-12-02 2015-11-06 2015-11-30 2017-12-16 2016-10-25 2016-07-16 2016-10-12 2018-07-03
 5 LAM   2016-12-13 2016-12-04 2016-12-10 2018-07-21 2017-10-13 2017-03-23 2017-10-02 2018-11-10
 6 LAM   2017-12-16 2017-04-18 2017-12-19 2019-05-10 2018-06-25 2017-11-20 2018-06-27 2019-10-11
 7 LAM   2018-07-13 2017-12-22 2018-07-15 2019-11-05 2018-11-06 2018-07-02 2018-11-04 2020-07-14
 8 LAM   2019-05-06 2018-07-19 2019-05-12 NA         2019-10-14 2019-03-06 2019-10-13 NA        
 9 LAM   2019-11-10 2019-05-11 2019-11-08 NA         2020-10-14 2019-10-08 2020-07-28 NA        
10 LAM   NA         2019-10-29 NA         NA         NA         2020-07-17 NA         NA        
> out %>% filter(ID == "LAM")
# A tibble: 10 × 9
   ID    EVI_SOS    NDVI_SOS   NIRv_SOS   kNDVI_SOS  EVI_EOS    NDVI_EOS   NIRv_EOS   kNDVI_EOS 
   <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 LAM   NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        
 2 LAM   NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         2016-07-25
 3 LAM   NA         NA         NA         2016-12-04 2015-11-01 2015-10-16 2015-10-30 2017-09-30
 4 LAM   2015-12-02 2015-11-06 2015-11-30 2017-12-16 2016-10-25 2016-07-16 2016-10-12 2018-07-03
 5 LAM   2016-12-13 2016-12-04 2016-12-10 2018-07-21 2017-10-13 2017-03-23 2017-10-02 2018-11-10
 6 LAM   2017-12-16 2017-04-18 2017-12-19 2019-05-10 2018-06-25 2017-11-20 2018-06-27 2019-10-11
 7 LAM   2018-07-13 2017-12-22 2018-07-15 2019-11-05 2018-11-06 2018-07-02 2018-11-04 2020-07-14
 8 LAM   2019-05-06 2018-07-19 2019-05-12 NA         2019-10-14 2019-03-06 2019-10-13 NA        
 9 LAM   2019-11-10 2019-05-11 2019-11-08 NA         2020-10-14 2019-10-08 2020-07-28 NA        
10 LAM   NA         2019-10-29 NA         NA         NA         2020-07-17 NA         NA
```

---

A general approach would be to a key/value data with 'key' being the unique 'ID' and then do a join with the original data and loop across the columns to convert to NA by comparing with the 'dates' column

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- data.table(ID = c("AUR", "LAM", "PO", "P01"), 
     dates = as.Date(c("2015-09-04", "2015-09-04", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-09")))
 out1 <- copy(df1)
nm1 <- grep("_SOS$", names(out1), value = TRUE)
setDT(out1)[df2, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, \(x) 
     fcase(x > dates, x)), on = .(ID), .SDcols = nm1]
```

---

Or the same method in `dplyr`

```
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(where(is_date), -dates),
        ~ case_when(.x > dates ~ .x)), dates = NULL)
# A tibble: 28 × 9
   ID    EVI_SOS    NDVI_SOS   NIRv_SOS   kNDVI_SOS  EVI_EOS    NDVI_EOS   NIRv_EOS   kNDVI_EOS 
   <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 AUR   NA         NA         NA         NA         2015-11-27 2015-11-29 NA         2015-11-25
 2 AUR   2016-01-05 2016-01-01 NA         2015-12-30 2016-10-10 2016-10-01 2015-11-29 2017-01-18
 3 AUR   2016-11-19 2016-11-05 2015-12-20 2017-02-15 2017-07-09 2017-07-28 2016-04-08 2017-07-09
 4 AUR   2017-09-12 2017-09-11 2016-05-01 2017-09-22 2018-02-15 2018-02-28 2017-01-25 2018-03-02
 5 AUR   2018-03-09 2018-03-17 2017-02-24 2018-03-17 2018-10-08 2018-10-08 2017-07-11 2018-10-01
 6 AUR   2018-11-16 2018-11-06 2017-08-01 2018-11-19 2019-07-21 2019-07-18 2018-02-28 2019-04-07
 7 AUR   2019-11-16 2019-10-27 2018-03-17 2019-04-17 2020-05-03 2020-05-03 2018-09-24 2019-07-11
 8 AUR   2020-05-21 2020-05-20 2018-10-17 2019-11-19 2020-11-19 2020-11-02 2019-01-24 2020-04-29
 9 AUR   NA         NA         2019-02-04 2020-05-19 NA         NA         2019-07-27 2020-10-27
10 AUR   NA         NA         2019-11-14 NA         NA         NA         2020-04-27 NA
```

Comment: I'm trying the first solution but I keep getting the following error: ``Error in across(where(is_date), ~case_when(.x > as.Date("2015-09-04" & : could not find function "across"``

Comment: ok, I've the 0.8.3